# Removing a textbox with a click of a button

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function

I'm trying to dynamically add and remove textboxes with a click of a button. The `add()` works but the `remove()` does not.

```
$ctra = 1;
function add() { 
    var ni = document.getElementById('myDiv');
    var numi = document.getElementById('theValue');
    var num = (document.getElementById('theValue').value -1)+ 2;
    numi.value = num;
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    var divIdName = 'my'+num+'Div';
    newdiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName);
    newdiv.innerHTML = "<table><tr><td width=159> Name</td>"+
            "<td> <input type='text' name='name' size=20> </td>"+
            "<td> Address </td>"+
            "<td> <input type='text' name='address' size=20> </td>"+
            "<td> Tel. No </td>"+
            "<td> <input type='text' name='telno' size=20><td> <button type='button' onclick='remove(divIdName);'>Remove</button></table>";

    if($ctra<5){
        ni.appendChild(newdiv);
        $ctra++;
    }
    $total = $ctra;
}
```

This is the `remove()`. It accepts the name of the `div`.

```
function remove(dId) {
    var ni = document.getElementById('myDiv');
    ni.removeChild(dId);
}
```

Please help me fix the problem. Thank you!

Comment: i think you need to do something like this `ni.removeChild(document.getElementById(dId));`

Comment: and also pass id in dId.. not name as you said.

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: I already did @Pete and @gaurav 's advices, hence `ni.removeChild(document.getElementById(dId));` and `remove(divIdName);` but I'm wondering why it's not yet working. :)

Comment: I am not using jQuery, @Mooseman

Comment: try adding `return false;` onto the end of your remove function - your page may be posting back and therefore reloading, also you have missed a couple of closing `td`s on the button line

Comment: Thank you! I tried adding `return false;` and I completed the `<td></td>` and added `</tr>` but it's still not functioning.

Comment: easier to show you jsfiddle! see answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the onclick to be the following:

```
onclick=\"remove('" + divIdName + "');\"
```

and then call the remove function like so

```
function remove(dId) {
  var ni = document.getElementById('myDiv');
  ni.removeChild(document.getElementById(dId));
  return false;
}
```

here is a jsfiddle of it working:   http://jsfiddle.net/JFzCf/5/

Comment: Oh! Thank you! That didn't occur to me easily. However, it just removes the button, not the whole row. :o

Comment: are you sure? if you look at the jsfiddle in the link above it is removing the whole row

Comment: Yes I am. It is not removing the whole row, just the remove button. :O

Comment: hmmm, well I don't know why it wouldn't work as I just used the code you pasted above with the changes in the answer above and it worked fine for me, could be browser issue? what browser are you using?

Comment: You are right, sir! :) At first I was using Chrome but after your comment, I tried IE and it now works! Is there a way to work this out with Chrome?

Comment: It's now working sir! Thank you very much for your help! Thank you for taking time! :)

Comment: I was just trying it out in chrome, what was the error?  you may also want to add `parseInt()` around `document.getElementById('theValue').value`

Answer (score 0):

your code structure gives like this

```
<div id='mydiv'>
  <div id='my'+num+'div'>
    //You had written table code here
  </div>
</div>
```

for removal `document.getElementById('myDiv');` 's child is your dynamically created `'my'+num+'div'`. please look into it

pass this divId to remove..hope you understand

Comment: My code only has `<div id="myDiv"> </div>`. I've changed `remove()`'s parameter by `divIdName` (no more `'my'+num+'div'`). `'my'+num+'div'` only happens if there's a newly added textbox. :)